# Which format of the url is correct while using an api with xml

Tags: excel, vba, api

When I try to access common/example api url with vba (excel), there is no problem.
The required URL is as follows: `"hppts://user:password@www.site.com/events/"`
When I copy the url in web-browser there is no problem.
But when using VBA is returning an error: "Method of Open object IServerXMLHTTPRequest2 has failed"

Code:

```
Dim http As Object, str As Variant
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

With http
    .Open "GET", "https://user:password@www.site.com/events/", False
    .send
    str = .responseText
End With

x = UBound(str)
```

Comment: `hppts` isn't a protocol I know of. Typo? `https`? Note HTTP and HTTPS are different protocols... you're sending an HTTP GET request, as if this were HTTP.

Comment: Try removing the password. Passwords in URLs were removed many years ago in Windows.